# Stuck in starting room in Stanley Parable

Tags: the-stanley-parable

I started a game of the Stanley Parable, I am in the starting office room. I walked out of the room, walked back into it and started clicking around. The door of the office closed on me and won't open no matter what I do. I have clicked on what seems like every object in the office and yet nothing is happening. What do I do? Is the game broken?

Please limit spoilers as much as possible.

Comment: Is there a "use key" at all? (E for example)

Comment: This game has many possible "endings". You have found one of them. Congratulations. Feel free to restart the game to try to find more.

Comment: Pretty sure there's an achievement for getting this ending.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get all the narrations implying that "ending"?

Comment: It was not an ending, the narrator was silent the whole time. I have gotten the locked in office ending and it is different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a bug where sometimes you can go back through a door while it is closing and locking. Try to avoid doing this, but if you get stuck as a result, simply hit Escape and begin the game from the start.

Answer (score 1):

This dose not sound like a bug, more like an Ending. In your case its the ending you just need to stand still and whait. Hf and good luck finding them all.
:D

Comment: No, there was an ending like that, but in this case I was in there for 10 minutes and nothing happened.

Comment: then maybe its realy a bug xD

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me. Instead of the room branching to two doors (where you're supposed to go left), there was just a tiny cupboard. Restarting fixed this issue.